# ajax contact form does not send email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

All day i trying to solve the problem but without success.
The form does not send a message and not written an error.

form.html

```
                <div class="ok" id="ok"></div>
                 <div id="data">              
                <div id="alert" class="alert_ig"></div>
                <form id="form" class=" clearfix"     method="POST" action="">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="{$smarty.cookies.nameuser}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
          </div>
        </div>


       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
             <input name="email" type="email" id="email" value="{$smarty.cookies.emailuser}" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
               <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

          </div>
        </div>

                         <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
                        <button style="margin-top:10px" id="submit" type="submit" class="bot_g">Send</button>

                          </div>
        </div>
                    </form>

       <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
    var form = $(this); 
    var error = false;
    if (!error) {
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({ 
           type: 'POST',
           url: '{$home}/system/modules/contacts/send.php',
           dataType: 'json', 
           data: data, 
             success: function(data){ 
                if (data.error.length > 0) {
                    $('#alert').html(""+data['error']+"");
                   $('#email').addClass("fill");
                } else {
                    $('#ok').html('send.');
                        $( "#data" ).css( "display","none" );

                }
             },
             return false;
        )};
  });  
 </script>  
                            </div>
```

send.php

```
   <?php
   require_once '../../inc/core.php';

  $name=Text(trim($_POST['name']));
  $email=Text(trim($_POST['email']));
  $subject=Text(trim($_POST['subject']));
  $text=Text(trim($_POST['text']));


 if(empty($name)){
 $json['error'] = 'Come on, you have a name don\'t you?';
 echo json_encode($json);
 exit;
 }

 if (mb_strlen($name) < 2 || mb_strlen($name) > 250){
$json['error'] = 'Your name must consist of at least 2 characters!';
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}

   if(empty($email)){
 $json['error'] = 'No Email, No Message!';
 echo json_encode($json);
 exit;
}

if (mb_strlen($email) < 5 || mb_strlen($email) > 64){
$json['error'] = 'Your email must consist of at least 5 characters!';
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
$json['error'] = 'Unknown characters in your e-mail!'; 
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}

if(empty($subject)){
$json['error'] = 'Um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.';
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}

if (mb_strlen($subject) < 5 || mb_strlen($subject) > 250){
$json['error'] = 'Your subject must consist of at least 5 characters!';
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}


 if (mb_strlen($text) < 2 || mb_strlen($text) > 10000){
$json['error']  = 'Thats All? Really?';
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
}

 $mailer = new phpmailer();
 $mailer->ContentType = "text/html";

 $mailer->From = $email;

  $mailer->Subject =  'New message from '.$home;
  $mailer->Body ="Subject: ".$subject."<br/>
            Name: ".$name."<br/>
            E-mail: ".$email."<br/>
            ".nl2br($text);

   $mailer->AddAddress($setup['emailadmin'], '');
  $mailer->Send();

    $json['error'] = 0; 
    echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

When is my problem with this code? 
I must use this send.php format, but may to change ajax and html form to working...

thanks

Comment: 1 - $home : is this variable print a local path or the apache public folder path ?
2 - how do you print this variable {$home}  ?
3 - to be able to debug it in a better way, you have to use the developer options ( right click , inspect element ), then open the network tab and click the button
you will be able to check the request data, request url , response. so you can identify the error reason

Comment: The URL work. $home = (my site url)

Comment: so inside your website, this path is the path of the file : /system/modules/contacts/send.php 
or something like /var/www/html/system/modules/contacts/send.php

Comment: would you like to give me a example? I can't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = $(this);
```

In this line $(this); refers to the submit button so var form, stores your submit button instead of the form element itself.

You may not see an error on the client-side, but if you try to debug the data sent to your server-side you will see something is wrong.

Try replacing $(this) with the selector that matches your form element.

Also, if you want to inform your users when the server returns an error like a 500 error for example, you can add an error callback to your $ajax function, along with the success callback you already have.

Have a look here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for the documentation.

Also add e.preventDefault() at the end of your event handler, to prevent the default action of submitting the form if you want to do an ajax submit.

Comment: Your url may be wrong as well. I don't see how javascript will know what is {$home}. Try to  hard-code it to debug it.
Also, remove return false from where you have it. I don't think it does anything after the success method.

Comment: would you want to give me a simple? I can't fix the problem.